# Unable to view connection settings from Administrator account

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am using Administrator account but I am unable to see the network adapter configuration. An error message says "You do not have sufficient privileges to view connection settings". Similarly on another server running the same operating system I am unable to view results on the GPO settings in GPMC.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a solution to this.

Visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932459

This explains the cause and the solution to follow.

Worked great for me on all my servers and computers